# How to get TextName of clicked grid in Android

Tags: android, grid-layout

Iam Making an application in android of a GridLayout with images and text in each grid and following is the code that I had made in FirstScreen.java and now I want that when I click on any image or text in the grid, a new screen or activity should open. But I am not getting how to open that

So please help me for the same???

```
package com.abc;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.abc.ImageAdapter.RecordHolder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstScreen extends Activity 
{
GridView gridView;
ImageAdapter imgAdapter;
ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();


protected void onCreate(Bundle b) 
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);


    Bitmap home = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.home);
    Bitmap cinema = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.cinema);
    Bitmap dining = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.dining);
    Bitmap electronic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.electronic);
    Bitmap fitness = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.fiteness);
    Bitmap gift = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.gift);
    Bitmap hotel = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.hotel);
    Bitmap lifestyle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.lifestyle);
    Bitmap moter = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.moter);
    Bitmap hospital = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.hospital);
    Bitmap salon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.salon);
    Bitmap travel = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.travel);


    gridArray.add(new Item(dining,"Food & Resturant"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(fitness,"Fitness & Health")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(salon,"Salons")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(home,"Home Furnishing")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(cinema,"Entertainment")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(moter,"Automobiles")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(lifestyle,"Lifestye")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(electronic,"Electronics")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(travel,"Travels & Lesiure")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(gift,"Books & Gifts")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(hospital,"Hospital")); 
    gridArray.add(new Item(hotel,"Hotel")); 


    GridView gridView  = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    imgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(imgAdapter);


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    { 

    }

    }); 


}

}
```

Comment: ImageAdapter adapter = (ImageAdapter) ((GridView) parent).getAdapter();
   Item item = adapter.getItem(position);
   String s = item.getTitle();
   if(s.equals("Hotel"))
   {
    System.out.print("Hotel Seecterd");
   }

Comment: I had added dis code.. But it dosent work in public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this `ImageAdapter` is your implementation.

You can get that adapter like this

```
ImageAdapter adpater = (ImageAdapter) ((GridView) parent).getAdapter();
```

Then get the item clicked

```
Item item = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Then do whatever you need with it.

Another solution is to get the item from your grid array.

```
Item item = gridArray.get(position);
```

Comment: ImageAdapter adapter = (ImageAdapter) ((GridView) parent).getAdapter(); Item item = adapter.getItem(position); String s = item.getTitle(); if(s.equals("Hotel")) { System.out.print("Hotel Seecterd"); }        I had added dis code.. But it dosent work in public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)

Comment: Is there anything? Is something written in console?
Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: ImageAdapter adpater = (ImageAdapter) ((GridView) parent).getAdapter();      Item item = adapter.getItem(position);            This code is giving error

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem was that I was using         android:onClick="imageClick". This was the problem..